# animate different trajectories

Tags: matlab, animation

I was trying to animate different moves in Matlab. This post [Matlab for loop animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463742/matlab-for-loop-animations) helped my a lot , but I would like to change moves after some time. Thus, after defining the trajectories I animated them. Could you please have a look?

I wanted to keep the speed of the dot fixed and thus I solved it with differential equations, which are defined at other files. I have defined also the times tf , tf1... I used exactly the same way as it was suggested at the above link, with hPoint.

```
tf=4*pi/15; % time at which 4pi are completed. speed=15
tf1= 2+tf; 
tf2= pi/15 +tf1;

[t,X]=ode45(@dif,[0 tf],[0 -15 -15])  
p1 = [X(:,2) X(:,3)];

[t,X2]=ode45(@dif2,[tf tf1],[-15 -15]) 
p1a = [X2(:,1) X2(:,2)];

[t,X3]=ode45(@dif,[tf1 tf2],[0 -15 +15]) 
p1b = [X3(:,2) X3(:,3)];

D = [p1(:,1) p1(:,2)
    p1a(:,1) p1a(:,2)
    p1b(:,1) p1b(:,2)];

hPoint = line('XData',D(1,1), 'YData',D(1,2), 'EraseMode',ERASEMODE, ...
    'Color','r', 'Marker','o', 'MarkerSize',50, 'LineWidth',1);
```

However, when I am trying to animate it, the dot stops a bit and then continues. Especially for the vector p1b, which is the third part( the upper circle). Any ideas about this behavior? Is there any way to make it stable and animate with the same speed? Thank you in advance !

Comment: not sure at all if this will help, but I recently saw the "comet"-plot command...

Comment: I don't see any animation code. How are you actually animating? Also the link you provided seems to be for generating movies (hence the calls to `getframe`) not animations. Do you actually want to create movies, i.e. video files/data?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. 

Lucius thanx, comet is nice I checked that.
@horchler Actually it would be better to have a video working. So I would go for getframe. It seems I can't improve it more. 

I have a blue trajectory that follows a path, and now I want to draw another that follows the blue but after some time. Is that possible and how? Alternatively, I would like to follow the red dot (like the example with the circle I mentioned above) with another dot, and keep fixed distance from it following the same path. That will generate the same result. 

Thank you in advance people !

Comment: With a movie the point is to record all of the frames at any rate. There may be jerkiness while actually running the `for` loop that calls `getframe`. This is expected. You're doing computation and you're doing frame grabbing and file/data writing. You only get smooth motion when you play back the the movie *afterwards*. However, even this can be troublesome if you have a slow computer, if you used the wrong codec, or if you simply tried to record frame as big as your screen for example (data rate).