# Time series animation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, animation, time-series

I am new to working with time series in Matlab and am struggling with getting this going. I have time series heat-transfer data (over a period of 20ms in steps of 1 microsecond) at these 11 locations (see code below). I am clueless as to how I could put them together to be able to generate a plot at each time step and use *getframe* at each timestep to make an animation. Any help on how to get started with this would be much appreciated. Here is a link to the 11 data files, providing time on column1 and heat transfer on column2: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oDAdapqvL-blecb7BOLzxpeiJBsqLd59

Please feel free to suggest any other tools (matplotlib/plotly etc.) that may be better in this scenario as well. Thanks a ton!

```
close all
clear all

x1=399.5
x2=400.5


y0=0 
y1=4
y2=8
y3=12
y4=16
y5=20
y6=-4
y7=-8
y8=-12
y9=-16
y10=-20

%The gauge locations for the first row will be [x1,y1], [x1,y3], [x1,y5], [x1,y6], [x1,y8],
%[x1,y10]

%The gauge locations for the second row will be [x2,y0], [x2,y2], [x2,y4], [x2,y7],
%[x2,y9]

figure

plot(x1,y1,'r.', x1,y3,'r.', x1, y5, 'r.', x1, y6, 'r.', x1, y8, 'r.', x1, y10, 'r.')
hold
plot(x2,y0,'b.', x2,y2,'b.', x2, y4, 'b.', x2, y7, 'b.', x2, y9, 'b.')
axis([390 410 -30 30])
```

Comment: See the videowriter doc: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.html - especially the last example

Comment: You can also read [Animation Techniques](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/animation-techniques-1.html) ... or take an example from this excellent answer which animate different objects and records it into a video: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7464653/3460361

Comment: Thanks for the links folks! I am having a look now and hopefully should be able to sort this out soon. Cheers!

Comment: You can also use the `pause` command with repeated plot calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Matlab you can use, as you said the `getFrame` and `writeVideo` functions. Ill explain it for a very general case, which you can then apply to yours.

Let's say we have a plot that changes it's data at every iteration inside a for loop (happens frequently when solving PDEs and so on) with an exemplary function `solverIteration` (made up...). We are plotting a vector `y` over our domain `x`.

In order to record the video we have to do the following:

```
video = VideoWriter('myVideo.avi'); %Create a video object
open(video); % Open video source - restricts the use of video for your program

for m=1:K
    y = solverIteration(y);
    plot(x,y);
    drawnow;

    vidFrame = getframe(gcf);
    % instead of gcf you can specify which figure you want to capture

    clf;

    writeVideo(video,vidFrame); % adds frames to the video

end


close(video);
```

This script is an example for how to record a video. There are several examples and explanations at the official [matlab site](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.html).

Comment: This is awesome, Pablo! Gives me a good place to start from....should hopefully be able to sort it out now. Cheers!

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem @user3792245? Let me know if you need some help! If not then please mark the question as answered :)

Comment: Yes, managed to get it working! I used some inputs from your code, but ended up writing a whole new piece of code to customize for my requirement. Here's the video: https://sreek_11-hotmail.tinytake.com/sf/Mjk5Nzc5MV84OTg2MjU4. Thanks for your inputs, Pablo!