# Can I run two independent while loops parallelly in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, while-loop, parallel-processing

While (condition):
{Move human-1 from a to b, total
5 steps
}
End

While (condition):
{Move human-2 from c to d, total 3 steps
}
End

In the above code, the top while loop is executed first and after it's done the second loop executes. The question is, is there any way to run the two independent while loops simultaneously? I need to show the movement of humans in plot(). Both of them should move in the plot window at the same time.

Thank you!

Comment: No. You need to combine the logic of the two loops into one loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try to see this: [Time series animation in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52757463/time-series-animation-in-matlab). I don't think you actually need the two while to run in parallel, but rather you need to plot the two paths simultaneously. You can store the steps as a time series and then using the reference in the link I attached for visualizing as a video simultaneously.

Comment: You should read about [Parallel Computing Toolbox](https://de.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/index.html)

Comment: you're right, I didn't think about using toolboxes at all. I still believe is more of a visualization problem rather than achieving parallel computations. Also because parallel computation would make sense to speed up some complex tasks, not much to write two while loops to generate a path, in my opinion at least :)

Comment: IMHO that's one of the problems on StackOverflow. People ask a simple question and often get an answer that doesn't answer the question but suggest to do something different. But this is a Q&A platform that should help other people in the future and if someone searches for _"Can I run two independent while loops parallelly in MATLAB?"_ there should be an answers for this and comments that there also different approaches.

Comment: It is not an answer to his/her direct question, but still a working answer that could solve his/her problem. The question is the one you say, but the problem he/she expresses when describing the question is actually different. And I use StackOverflow also to learn about different ways of thinking about a problem and discover different paths to reach a same solution. I could have written that as a comment rather than an answer? Absolutely. In my opinion, a bigger problem on StackOverflow is the attitude of many users that always reply in a bitter manner, especially when dealing with newbies.

Comment: The bitter manner probably is probably justified by the fact that most newbies obviously didn't read the [tour] and don't follow the rules of this platform.

Comment: In the tour there is also "Remember: we're all here to learn, so be friendly and helpful!". Bitter manners are never justified. I still think my answer is appropriate. Have a good day!

Comment: @Thomas: I agree with BNQ here. Parallel computation is just not appropriate for OP's problem. If the title of the question had used "simultaneously" instead of "parallelly" [sic], I'm sure you wouldn't have thought of parallel computing for this problem. OP is obviously not fluent in English, you can't use a single word to justify if an answer is appropriate or not, ignoring the rest of the question text.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a combination of [`parfeval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parallel.pool.parfeval.html) to launch the work in parallel, and [`DataQueue`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parallel.pool.dataqueue.html) to update the graphics while the execution is ongoing.

The idea with the `DataQueue` is that each worker will send an update back to the client, and then the client connects up an `afterEach` handler to update the graphics. Here's an example:

```
% Need a parallel pool of size at least 2
if isempty(gcp)
    parpool('local', 2);
end
% Set up some simple graphics
ax = gca();
cla(ax);
ax.XLim = [-10 10];
ax.YLim = [-10 10];
hold on;
h1 = plot(0, 0, 'MarkerSize', 10, 'Marker', 'o');
h2 = plot(0, 0, 'MarkerSize', 10, 'Marker', '*');

% Set up a DataQueue to receive data from the workers.
dq = parallel.pool.DataQueue();
% Hook up afterEach so that iUpdate is called each time
% a worker calls "send"
afterEach(dq, @(data) iUpdate(data, {h1, h2}));

% Use parfeval to launch the work in parallel. Pass in the
% DataQueue so that the workers can send results back to the client
fut1 = parfeval(@iDoWork, 0, dq, 1);
fut2 = parfeval(@iDoWork, 0, dq, 2);

% This gets called each time a worker calls "send" - it
% updates one or other of the handles in the cell array
% h12
function iUpdate(data, h12)
h = h12{data(1)};
set(h, 'XData', data(2), 'YData', data(3));
end

% This is the function that the workers execute in parallel
% It performs a computation, and then sends the output
% to the DataQueue dq.
function iDoWork(dq, index)
count = 0;
xLoc = 0;
yLoc = 0;
while count < 100 && max(abs([xLoc, yLoc])) < 10
    xLoc = xLoc + rand() - 0.5;
    yLoc = yLoc + rand() - 0.5;
    data = [index, xLoc, yLoc];
    send(dq, data);
    pause(0.1);
    count = 1 + count;
end
end
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't know this was possible. But this is a way over-complicated solution to OP's simple problem. OP doesn't really need to run two loops in parallel, they just need to do two trivial computations within each loop iteration.

Comment: If all you know how to use is a hammer... ;)